# Question about the measure in the partition function of a lattice Yang-Mills theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, partition-function, lattice-gauge-theory

This can seem like a dumb question but the partition function of a lattice pure gauge field theory in euclidean space is:
\begin{equation}
Z=\int \prod_{x,\mu} dU_\mu(x)\,e^{-S_W[U_\mu(x)]}\,\,\,,\,\,\,S_W[U_\mu(x)] \sim\beta \sum_x \sum_{\mu,\nu} \text{Re Tr}\left[ U_{\mu \nu}(x) \right]
\end{equation}
Where $U_\mu(x)$ is a Wilson line, and $U_{\mu \nu}(x)$ is a Wilson loop around a plaquette $P_{\mu \nu}(x)$. Since we are taking the trace of the Wilson loops neither the off-diagonal elements nor the order in which we sum the diagonal elements are relevant. Furthermore, since Wilson loops are products of Wilson lines, using an alternating pattern on the space (in 2D it would look like a chessboard) one can change the measure $\prod_{x,\mu} dU_\mu(x)$ into $\prod_{x_{1/2};\mu,\nu} dU_{\mu \nu}(x)$. Here $x_{1/2}$ means that we only take half of the plaquettes in our pattern to avoid redundancies, and this leads to a prefactor in the partition function of the form $e^{-S_W[U_{\mu \nu}(x_{2,1})]}$, where $x_{2/1}$ are the other emplacements not taken in count.

So my question is: Why don't we simplify the measure $\prod_{x,\mu} dU_\mu(x)$ into $\prod_{x_{1/2};\mu,\nu} d[\text{Tr}\,(U_{\mu\nu}(x))]$, letting just a new prefactor before the partition function?